# How do I sum over columns in a data frame, based on index number?

Tags: r, statistics

I have many dbf tables (outputs from an analysis in a different program) that need to be read into R and summarized. Each dbf has a number of columns that represent different edge or core habitat classes. Depending on a previous analysis, different dbf files will have differing numbers of the core and edge classes (columns), so I can’t simply sum across a consistent range of index values, [2:4], for instance.

To determine which columns are present (for summing) and the index number of those columns, I have written the following loop. This checks the current table names against a master list (ae) and if the column is present, gets the index number of the column in the current data frame:

```
#read in all the possible edge column names
    ae<-c("VALUE_1","VALUE_3","VALUE_5","VALUE_9","VALUE_33","VALUE_35","VALUE_37","VALUE_65","VALUE_67","VALUE_69","VALUE_101","VALUE_103","VALUE_105","VALUE_109","VALUE_133","VALUE_135","VALUE_137","VALUE_165","VALUE_167","VALUE_169")

#Create and empty data frame and turn off stringsAsFactors:
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
edgeIndices<-data.frame()

#for each column name, get the index number 
for (i in ae) {
  index<-which(colnames(currfile)==i)

  #check to see if ae is in currfile
  #if it is, get the index number, if not skip ahead
  if (length(index)>0){ edgeIndices<-rbind(edgeIndices,c(index, i)) }
  else {}
}

#for some reason the index number is coming in as a character
#also, I need to figure out how to bring in the label without 
# it forcing to factor (I     have changed the global parameter for now)

#name the columns
names(edgeIndices)=c("Index","Label")

#change the index to a number:
edgeIndices$Index<-as.numeric(edgeIndices$Index)
```

Here’s my output:

```
  Index   Label
1 3       VALUE_1
2 4       VALUE_3
3 5       VALUE_9
4 7       VALUE_33
5 8       VALUE_35
6 9       VALUE_65
7 10      VALUE_67
8 12      VALUE_101
```

So, now my question is, how do I pass the Index values to a `rowSums()` function so that only the columns with the appropriate Index # are summed?

For instance, in the case below, only Values 1,3, and 9 should be summed, which would be indices 3,4, and 5

```
OID_    VALUE_0 VALUE_1 VALUE_3 VALUE_9 SUM
4473    181800  15300   200700  0   216000
4474    239400  6300    153000  0   159300
4475    296100  13500   86400   0   99900
```

Comment: huh. Just figured it out! 
rowSums(currfile[,edgeIndices$Index])

Comment: go ahead and answer your own question below and mark it correct when you can.

Comment: thanks- will do in 7 hours (newbie stackoverflow rules)

Comment: The reason your numbers were converted to "character" is that you were using `rbind` with some of the inputs as "character". Matrices all need to be the same storage mode and will loose attributes.

Comment: @DavidLaPuma, it's been 7 hours ;-)